# transform-origin and perspective with Safari

Tags: html, css, safari, css-transforms

I am trying to make a cube rotate in css3 / javascript, and I observe differences between Safari and other browsers.
I already read some posts about that on stackoverflow, but I didn't manage to fix my problem.

I position initially the faces of the cubes using translations and rotations, and I don't assign any transform origin.
When I rotate the cube, I assign the tranform-origin so the axis is at the center of it, then rotateY. I just add a class to the box:

```
.show-front {
    transform-origin: center center $transformOrigin;
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
}
```

I created a codepen here: https://codepen.io/3MO/pen/eWZLNG

My problem is, it works properly with Chrome and Firefox, but Safari zooms the face showing up. It seems it comes from the css attribute `perspective`. If I remove it, there is no zoom, it is consistent between browsers but I am kind of loosing the... perspective during the rotation.

I created another codepen here to show the result without perspective: https://codepen.io/3MO/pen/XRdPmV

How can I have a nice rotation under Safari without any zoom effect brought by the `perspective` attribute?

Is there a way to have an implementation consistent between all browsers?

Thanks !

Comment: Have you applied vendor prefixes to all the CSS3 properties?

Comment: For safari it's -webkit-, I tried and it didn't change anything. I am thinking of another solution, instead of using transform-origin, doing a translateZ during the animation. I will test that tonight.

Comment: @Joel have you found a solution yet?

Comment: Hello @psikai, no sure, it was a long time ago and I moved on.